# i would like to query for a specific feature in a feature collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geojson, mongoose-schema

```js
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var GeoJSON = require('mongoose-geojson-schema');
var db = require('./connection.js');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const senuSchema = new Schema({
  type:mongoose.Schema.Types.FeatureCollection,
  name:String,
  crs:Object,
  features:Array
});
const model = db.model('senu', senuSchema, 'senu');
console.log('succefully made model');
model.findOne({name:'senu'},function(err,doc){
  if (err){console.log(err);}
  else{
    console.log(doc);
  }
});
```

The code gets a mondodb  database connection then I create a model for the data I'm trying to retrieve but when I run it, i get the whole object.

I would like to query for a specific feature within the object which is in a features array in the object.

Comment: `findOne` returns the entire document unless you use a projection.  I don't think projection will let you pick individual values from an array, but you should be able to do that in an aggregation pipeline with `$filter`.

Comment: If by feature you mean fields from the document, you may consider 'select'